# ExpectedException xunit .net core

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, .net-core, xunit, xunit.net

I'm writing unit test for **core** application. Im trying to check, that my class throws exception. But **ExpectedException** attribute throws compile exception:

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ExpectedException' could not
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   EventMessagesBroker.Logic.UnitTests..NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0

My code:

```
[Fact]
[ExpectedException(typeof(MessageTypeParserException))]
public void TestMethod1_Error_twoMathces()
{
    var message = "some text";
    var parser = new MessageTypeParser();
    var type = parser.GetType(message);
    Assert.Equal(MessageType.RaschetStavkiZaNalichnye, type);
}
```

so, is there any correct way to achieve that?

Comment: Don't use xunit without reading https://xunit.github.io/docs/comparisons.html

Comment: 3 years late...ExpectedException comes from MSTest Nuget...haven't had any luck cross-use that Nuget w/ Xunit

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use `Assert.Throws` on code where exception expected:

```
[Fact]
public void TestMethod1_Error_twoMathces()
{
    var message = "some text";
    var parser = new MessageTypeParser();
    Assert.Throws<MessageTypeParserException>(() => parser.GetType(message));
}
```

Comment: yeap, i use this way. Think this is only solution

Comment: Just for the record, xunit does not support ExpectedException and supports the way shown in the answer. As described in more detail here: https://xunit.github.io/docs/comparisons.html

If you wanted to follow the Triple A syntax for unit testing then you could assign parser.GetType(message) to an Action and assert that your action throws an exception.

Comment: We can also use `Record.Exception` method and later on verify using `Assert.NotNull` method and `Assert.IsType<>` method. See https://www.richard-banks.org/2015/07/stop-using-assertthrows-in-your-bdd.html